# Using CreateParameters with a variable size parameter

Tags: sql, vba, sql-server-2008, excel, stored-procedures

I need to call a stored procedure from Excel, passing several values entered by a user as parameters. I have almost achieved this with a Macro using the following Parameters collection.

```
Set ADOCmd = New ADODB.Command

With ADOCmd
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Department", adChar, adParamInput, Len(cDept), cDept)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@title", adChar, adParamInput, Len(cTitle), cTitle)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@name", adChar, adParamInput, Len(cName), cName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@email", adChar, adParamInput, Len(cEmail), cEmail)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@tel_no", adChar, adParamInput, Len(cTel), cTel)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@mob_no", adChar, adParamInput, Len(cMob), cMob)
End With
```

This will work just fine if all of the values have been filled out by the user. However if anything is left blank the following error occurs.

```
Run-time error:'3708':
Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.
```

I'm led to believe this is because the Size parameter passed in the CreateParameter function is zero. Is there any way I can get around this? Shouldn't it accept zero as a valid Size if the string entered is zero characters long?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the columns in the table are char as opposed to varchar?

Comment: The length should be the maximum size for the parameter, so it's the length of the parameter as declared in your stored procedure, not the length of the string being passed into it.

Comment: Alex K and Tom H, good shout, thanks.

I had tried already to use the max size for the column, but then it added spaces onto the end of the strings. I changed this to adVarChar and added the max size of the column again as the Size and it removed the spaces.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex K and Tom H helped me here.

I changed the type to adVarChar and the size to the maximum size allowed by the column, which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can make size an optional parameter in your stored procedure. Then add logic to change it from null to 0. If you do set a size it will keep the value you pass.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SQL_Procedure
     @size INT = null,

AS Begin 
--if @size comes over as null make it 0
   set @size=ISNULL(@size,0)
rest of you SP
```

END